# 2013 Buick Verano Engine jerks only when stopped at stop sign or red light while still in drive

Tags: oil, stall, buick, solenoid

I have a 2013 Buick Verano with about 110,000 miles. A couple years ago my car stalled and I had a code to replace the solenoids in which did and the problem seemed to go away. About a year later while stoping at a light or stop sign, still in drive with brakes on, the car would violently shake to the point where I felt the car would stall. Again I replaced the solenoids and got an oil change and it seemed to fix the issue. Last week I had the same issue and again replaced the solenoids but this time I discovered my oil was bone dry. After filling it up it ran great for a couple days and now it is doing it again. It only does it if I run the car hard for about 30 or so minutes on the highway and then come to a stop. On short trips it does not do it. Hope this is enough information that someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What solenoids was it you were replacing? What were the code(s)? What do you mean by "run the car hard"?

Comment: Was the oil that was "bone dry" the engine oil or the transmission oil?